# SoapException - Missing Header Information

Tags: c#, .net, xml, soap, soapui

I am trying to get some data from a web service, using a simple console application, however I am getting this error:

> SoapException was unhandled
>   Error - Missing Header Information.

I have already tried the below articles:

- http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/709641/ERROR-SOAP-Header-Missing
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y4t36w86(v=vs.80).aspx

But I am not allowed to work on the WebServer side, so there is not much I can do.

Code:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            myWS.WServer WebService = new myWS.WServer();
            string[] myMethods = WebService.GetMethods();
        }
    }
}
```

Follows the full error message:

> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException was unhandled
>   HResult=-2146233087   Message=Error - Missing Header Information.
>   Source=System.Web.Services   Actor=Unknown Error   Lang=""
>   Node=Unknown Error   Role=""   StackTrace:
>          em System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage
>   message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean
>   asyncCall)
>          em System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String
>   methodName, Object[] parameters)
>          em ConsoleApplication3.myWS.WServer.GetMethods() na c:\VS\ConsoleApplication3\ConsoleApplication3\Web
>   References\myWS\Reference.cs:linha 532
>          em ConsoleApplication3.Program.Main(String[] args) na c:\VS\ConsoleApplication3\ConsoleApplication3\Program.cs:linha 14
>          em System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
>          em System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>          em Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>          em System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>          em System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>          em System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>          em System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          em System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()   InnerException:

Despite the problem above, using `SoapUI` and `XML`, it does works well.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ver="http://www.multispeak.org/Version_3.0">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <ver:MultiSpeakMsgHeader Version="3.0" UserID="myId" Pwd="myPwd" AppName="?" AppVersion="?" Company="?" CSUnits="feet" CoordinateSystem="?" Datum="?" SessionID="?" PreviousSessionID="?" ObjectsRemaining="?" LastSent="?" RegistrationID="?"/>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ver:GetMethods/>
   </soapenv:Body>
```

I am thinking that the problem is related to authentication, since I do not set any credentials in the console applications.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to solve it.
It was related to the authentication, as the example below:

```
WebService .MultiSpeakMsgHeaderValue = new MultiSpeakMsgHeader {
    Pwd = "***",
    UserID = "***"
};
```

Before call the methods.